Add transparency to raster bands where did not exist before
My original radar image is a tiff image with one single band.
    Metadata:AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   20326.997, 7287235.388) (  0d10'57.36"E, 54d36'49.02"N)
Lower Left  (   20326.997, 6253621.827) (  0d10'57.36"E, 48d52'28.80"N)
Upper Right ( 1123614.355, 7287235.388) ( 10d 5'36.96"E, 54d36'49.02"N)
Lower Right ( 1123614.355, 6253621.827) ( 10d 5'36.96"E, 48d52'28.80"N)
Center      (  571970.676, 6770428.607) (  5d 8'17.16"E, 51d50' 7.65"N)
Band 1 Block=1281x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=-6.000 Max=5.999 
  Minimum=-6.000, Maximum=5.999, Mean=0.122, StdDev=3.442
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5.999450052
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.12197202269074
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-5.999813778
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=3.4418456115023
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=8.112

THis image is a black & white image with an opacity of 1. The nodata -9999 pixels are solid black. I must make the -9999 transparent to correctly illustrate the cloud cover.
Initially I am using gdalwarp to add a new alpha channel:
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata -9999 -dstalpha -of ENVI "$file" "$tempOutputFilePath"

The result seems good to me:
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  Band_1=Band 1
  Band_2=Band 2
Band 1 Block=1568x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Minimum=-6.000, Maximum=5.999, Mean=0.123, StdDev=3.441
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5.999450052
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.12257220293462
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-5.999813778
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=3.441050203441
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=8.181
Band 2 Block=1568x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Band 2
  Minimum=255.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=255.000, StdDev=0.000
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=255
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100

Where I read this as it has created band 2 and set 100% of the pixels to 255.  So now I must use gdal_calc to compare the two bands 1 & 2.
gdal_calc.py -A "$tempOutputFilePath" --A_band=1 \
    -B "$tempOutputFilePath" --B_band=2 --outfile="$tempOutputFilePath" \
    --calc="B=255 * (A != -9999)" --NoDataValue=0 --type='Float64' \
    --overwrite --format=ENVI

which as far as I understand, this is trageting band B and setting 255 to all pixels from A which are NOT -9999 or equal to the nodata value.  Then I am translating this new output to MBTiles:
gdal_translate -of MBTiles -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG -a_nodata 0 "$tempOutputFilePath" "$outputFilePath"
    echo "Converted $file to MBTiles format."

Which results in a giant solid white block.  SO when I re examine the tiff after the calc, I find that Band 2 seems to have been removed and band 1 remains:
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  Band_1=Band 1
  Band_2=Band 2
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.1826005,  54.6136175) (  0d10'57.36"E, 54d36'49.02"N)
Lower Left  (   0.1826005,  48.8734029) (  0d10'57.36"E, 48d52'24.25"N)
Upper Right (  10.0952178,  54.6136175) ( 10d 5'42.78"E, 54d36'49.02"N)
Lower Right (  10.0952178,  48.8734029) ( 10d 5'42.78"E, 48d52'24.25"N)
Center      (   5.1389091,  51.7435102) (  5d 8'20.07"E, 51d44'36.64"N)
Band 1 Block=1568x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=-6.000 Max=5.999 
  Minimum=-6.000, Maximum=5.999, Mean=0.123, StdDev=3.441
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5.999450052
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.12257220293462
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-5.999813778
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=3.441050203441
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=8.181
Input file size is 1568, 908

This is extremely painful for 3 days now. But the gdal_calc is my newest change and makes a little sense. If I understand it all correctly, the original tiff has a color interpreter of gray and is a solid black/white tiff.  gdalwarp adds a new band and set all pixels to 255 or white. Then the gdal_calc should modify band 2 changing all pixels to 255 which are not suposed to be transparent from band 1 or A. BUT to me it did not change the already current nodata pixels to 0 as I do not see how that is represented in the code.  The desired output is a transparent black backgroud as we would all imagine it should be. Anyone have any good input on this and what I am doing wrong? This is my full bash script:
# Run GDAL commands
    gdalinfo -stats "$file" > tempinfo.txt
    min=$(grep "STATISTICS_MINIMUM=" tempinfo.txt | cut -d'=' -f2)
    max=$(grep "STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=" tempinfo.txt | cut -d'=' -f2)

    echo "BEFORE"
    info=$(gdalinfo -stats "$file")
    echo "$info"

    # Use gdalwarp to reproject and set nodata
    gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata -9999 -dstalpha -of ENVI "$file" "$tempOutputFilePath"

    echo "AFTER"
    info2=$(gdalinfo -stats "$tempOutputFilePath")
    echo "$info2"

    # Adjust the alpha band where no data values are present
    gdal_calc.py -A "$tempOutputFilePath" --A_band=1 \
    -B "$tempOutputFilePath" --B_band=2 --outfile="$tempOutputFilePath" \
    --calc="B=255 * (A != -9999)" --NoDataValue=0 --type='Float64' \
    --overwrite --format=ENVI

    echo "AFTER CALC"
    info3=$(gdalinfo -stats "$tempOutputFilePath")
    echo "$info3"

    #gdal_translate -of MBTiles -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG -scale "$min" "$max" 0 255 -a_nodata -9999 "$tempOutputFilePath" "$outputFilePath"
    gdal_translate -of MBTiles -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG -a_nodata 0 "$tempOutputFilePath" "$outputFilePath"
    echo "Converted $file to MBTiles format."

The MBTile is being displayed in a ReactJS application using MapBox-gl as such:
map.current.addSource(layerName, {
                    scheme: 'tms',
                    type: 'raster',
                    tiles: [`http://localhost:3067/tiles/${layerName}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`],
                    tileSize: 128 // 1281
                });
                map.current.addLayer({
                    id: `${t.siteId}_${t.productType}_${t.range}`,
                    type: 'raster',
                    source: layerName,
                    paint: {
                        'raster-opacity': 1 // Optionally set the opacity
                    }
                });


What software are you trying to display/view your data in that doesn't understand that NoData values (in -9999 your case) are null and shouldn't be displayed...?

Is a good question. I am using MabBox in a reactJS application. But, doesnt there have to be a band to read in the first place? And if I view he resulting PNG tile in GIMP, it has no transparency.

The nodata is marked correctly in your data. Nodata is just an agreement between the data and the viewer software "I tell you that you should render pixels with value x transparent". That agreement is not defined in the TIFF specification. It comes from GDAL https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#nodata-value but many GIS software can interpret the TIFFTAG_GDAL_NODATA tag. Do you know if your software would prefer an alpha band?

I dont know that at all. This is new to me. I assumed this was the way to generate a valid PNG. What led me here was the abscence of the gdal_calc renders a solid black image. Adding scale revealed the clouds by adjusting the contrast. Research reveals that adding an alpha layer to manipulate is the answer. I prefer this over using "sharp" for example to modify the PNG as the results are exactly that the black is transparent, but the fuzziness is poor. I prefer to do this without sharp

Sounds like you want to create a PNG to display in Mapbox that has clouds only and everything else is transparent? Your input tiff has values from min=-6.000 to max=5.999. Is there a threshold above/below that you consider to be cloud? Do you want all cloud to be completely white or do you want the higher values to be whiter and the lower values greyer?
